# Как сделать поиск и замену новой строки и точки в notepad++

Tags: notepad++

В файле стилей css нужно всем классам добавить "new-", как выполнить поиск новой строки и "." и замену на новая строка ".new-", чтобы у всех классов стало ".new-старый класс"?

делаю так:

поиск

```
^\..*\s{$
```

замена

```
^\.new.*\s{$
```

но тогда все стили меняются на само рег выражение ^.new.*\s{$

Answer (score 2):

Найти `^\.` заменить `.new-` галочка регулярные выражения 

для `.tours__items .tour-container`

Найти   `^\.(.+)\.`
заменить `.new-$1.new-`


Если будет жадничать, слишком много захватывать то добавить 
Найти `^\.(.+?)\.`
Заменить `.new-$1.new-`

Comment: спасибо, но к сожалению, как оказалось это не решает проблему, тк есть еще стили такого вида
`.tours__items .tour-container и у второго класса тоже надо заменить точку на .new-
```

Comment: @dava002 можно сначала первый вариант затем второй